# check if a string contains same character in R

Tags: r, regex, string, grepl

```
Countries <- c("AAAAAAA", sample(c("India","USA","UK","SSS"),20,replace=TRUE))
df1 <- data.frame(Countries)
df1
```

I want to check if a string contains same character

```
library(stringi)
df1$All_S<-stri_count_fixed(df1$Countries,"S")==nchar(df1$Countries)
df1

      Countries All_S
  1    AAAAAAA FALSE
  2         UK FALSE
  3      India FALSE
  4      India FALSE
  5        SSS  TRUE
  6         UK FALSE
  7        SSS  TRUE
  8        SSS  TRUE
  9      India FALSE
  10       SSS  TRUE
  11        UK FALSE
  12     India FALSE
  13       SSS  TRUE
  14       USA FALSE
  15        UK FALSE
  16        UK FALSE
  17       SSS  TRUE
  18       SSS  TRUE
  19     India FALSE
  20       USA FALSE
  21       USA FALSE
```

However this only check if string contains only "S". How can I change it to make it work for any string. In above example, this means first entry `AAAAAAA` will also be True

Comment: what do you mean with 'any string'? Please provide some example output as well

Comment: Thanks, Just edited the question to provide more explaination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another possibility:

```
sapply(strsplit(df1$Countries, ""), function(x) all(x == x[1]))
```

Comment: I think they want to catch "AAAAAAA", too.

Comment: aah.. missed that.. updated answer

Answer (score 2):

I would use `grepl` here:

```r
df1$All_S <- grepl("^S+$", df1$Countries)
```

To do the above for *any* letter, then use:

```r
df1$All_S <- grepl("^(\\w)\\1*$", df1$Countries)
```

Comment: I just edited my question to make it clearer. The solution I am looking for is any string which has same characters to be true. This means the first entry `AAAAAAA`  should also be true

Comment: @89_Simple I guess the name `All_S` along with `AAAAAAA` being reported as false threw me off.

Comment: Sorry about that. My bad

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
transform(
    df1,
    All_same = grepl("^(.)(\\1)+$", Countries)
)
```

which gives something like

```
   Countries All_same
1    AAAAAAA     TRUE
2         UK    FALSE
3         UK    FALSE
4         UK    FALSE
5        USA    FALSE
6         UK    FALSE
7        USA    FALSE
8        USA    FALSE
9        USA    FALSE
10        UK    FALSE
11     India    FALSE
12       SSS     TRUE
13       USA    FALSE
14       USA    FALSE
15     India    FALSE
16       USA    FALSE
17        UK    FALSE
18       SSS     TRUE
19     India    FALSE
20        UK    FALSE
21        UK    FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

"I want to check if a string contains same character" -- this leaves open the possibility that

- (i) the string contains not-same characters too ("AAB")
- (ii) the same characters can, but need not, be adjacent (e.g., "ABA")
- (iii) the string contains **only** same characters

The three conditions call for slightly different regex solutions:

**solution (i)**:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(Same = str_detect(Countries, "(.)\\1+"))
```

The three conditions call for different solutions:

**solution (ii)**:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(Same = str_detect(Countries, "(.).*\\1+"))
```

**solution (iii)**:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(Same = str_detect(Countries, "^(.)\\1+$"))
```

Comment: Note the pattern you want here _might_ be `^(.)\\1*$`, assuming that a single letter counts as a match.  Also, no need to place the capture group `(\1)*` in parentheses.  We don't need to capture again beyond the first letter.

Comment: Yes, indeed. All agreed!